# How to make the Media Foundation-based playback open and fast seek MP4 HTTP file that moov is at end?

Tags: video, mp4, ms-media-foundation

- For historical reasons, we have many MP4 local or remote files that are generated naturally, that is, MOOV is at the end. At present, for hardware acceleration to improve performance, we have migrated from ffmpeg / ffplay to Media Foundation.
- refer to [Media Session Playback Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-session-playback-example) and [ofxWMFVideoPlayer](https://github.com/secondstory/ofxWMFVideoPlayer): When playing back remote MP4 (HTTP) files, the first frame display is slow, and the seek is so slow (15s-90s); we tested it: If MOOV is at front, then these operations are very fast.
- so is there any special setting needed here?

Answer (score 0):

If stock MPEG-4 Media Source shipped does not meet expectations you do not have much of choices to make things better. Apart from replacing it with [custom built media source primitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source) you could possibly supply your own implement a byte stream ([`IMFByteStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfbytestream)) on top of HTTP connectivity. By doing that you would be able to create [`MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-mfcreatesourcereaderfrombytestream) MP4 source reader from your byte stream, and in your byte stream you would be able to capture requests to read from the end of the file and supply this data reading it ahead of the body of the media and caching already read chunks respectively.